# Cannot load JSON file using THREE.JSONLoader ( XMLHttpRequest cannot load )

Tags: json, three.js

I made a simple model in Blender and exported it in JSON format using the exporter add-on for three.js (so far so good). I have the JSON file titled testplane.js in the same directory as my start HTML file Pilproject.html, and am now trying to add it to my scene using the following code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "testplane.js", 
            function( geometry) {
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial );
            mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( mesh );
            }
);
```

I get a black scene when I run it and have this in the debugger:

> [image: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/project1/testplane.js. Choss origin requests are only supported for HTTP.]

Is the problem with the code for loading the JSON file into my scene, elsewhere, or both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three.JSL: Does local server needed for loading Blender model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272226/three-jsl-does-local-server-needed-for-loading-blender-model)

Comment: @gaitat, I saw that and noticed I had already set the --allow-file-access-from-files flag in chrome. I don't think that is the issue but maybe I need to set up a http server? Not sure

Comment: What does Firefox say?

Comment: Ok so I used the allow access from files flag running from the command prompt instead of adding it through properties and it seems to be loading the model now ( though untextured but probably unrelated ). Thank I think that this is resolved now.